# ¿Puede __init__ retornar una subclase?

Tags: python, diseño-de-clases

Tengo una clase base `Numero` y numerosas subclases especializadas (decimal, flotante, tiempos, lat/lon, etc). La clase base y las subclases se instancian a partir de la representación como string:

```
valor1 = NumeroEntero("10")
valor2 = NumeroDecimal("10.1")
valor3 = NumeroPosicion("40.423261°N 3.712594°W")
```

Lo que busco es poder decir simplemente

```
valor1 = Numero("10")  => type(valor1) es NumeroEntero
valor2 = Numero("10.1") => type(valor2) es NumeroDecimal
valor3 = Numero("40.423261°N 3.712594°W") => type(valor3) es NumeroPosicion
```

y obtener como resultado tres objetos de subclases distintas.

Este código (ilegal) muestra lo que pretendo:

```
class Numero:
    def __init__(self, valor: str):
        if '.' in valor:
            return NumeroDecimal(valor)
        else:
            return NumeroEntero(valor)

class NumeroEntero(Numero):
    def __init__(self, valor: str):
        self.valor = int(valor)

class NumeroDecimal(Numero):
    def __init__(self, valor: str):
        self.valor = float(valor)


var1 = Numero("10")  => type(var1) == NumeroEntero
var2 = Numero("10.0") => type(var2) == NumeroDecimal
```

Podría escribir simplemente una función que reciba el texto, lo examine y devuelva el objeto apropiado, pero lo encuentro poco elegante.

¿Alguien conoce un hack para resolverlo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es una *factoría*, es decir un método o función que pueda crear objetos. `__init__()` no es una factoría, no puede crear objetos, tan solo inicializar objetos previamente creados. De hecho `__init__()` nunca retorna nada (y si lo hiciera, el valor retornado es ignorado).

Pero toda clase tiene un método `__new__()` que es el encargado de crear el objeto, y al que Python llama antes de llamar a `__init__()`. Es en ese método donde debes hacer tu "magia".

El problema es que la cosa no es tan simple como:

```
# ESTO NO VA A FUNCIONAR, BUCLE INFINITO DE RECURSION
class Numero:
    def __new__(cls, valor: str):
      if '.' in valor:
          return NumeroDecimal(valor)
      else:
          return NumeroEntero(valor)
```

La razón por la que no funciona es que al intentar una instanciación de objeto a través de la sintaxis `NumeroDecimal()`, python llamará a `NumeroDecimal.__new__()`, y al no estar éste implementado llamará al `__new__()` de su clase base, con lo que acabamos entrando otra vez por `Numero.__new__()` y estamos en un bucle infinito de recursión que termina cuando rompe la pila.

Eso obliga a usar esta otra sintaxis un poco más farragosa:

```
# Esto si fuciona
class Numero:
    def __new__(cls, valor: str):
      if '.' in valor:
          return super().__new__(NumeroDecimal)
      else:
          return super().__new__(NumeroEntero)

class NumeroEntero(Numero):
    def __init__(self, valor: str):
        self.valor = int(valor)

class NumeroDecimal(Numero):
    def __init__(self, valor: str):
        self.valor = float(valor)


var1 = Numero("10")
var2 = Numero("10.0")
print(type(var1), type(var2))
```

Resultado:

```
<class '__main__.NumeroEntero'> <class '__main__.NumeroDecimal'>
```

Al hacerlo de esta forma: `super().__new__(NumeroDecimal)` estamos invocando al `__new__()` de la clase base de `Numero`. En este caso "no hay" clase base, por lo que en realidad su clase base es `object`. Este es la clase Python de la que deriva cualquier otra, y que contiene el método `__new__()` que es en última instancia quien crea los objetos (reserva la memoria, etc... esas cosas que ocurren detrás del telón). El método `__new__()` siempre recibe como primer parámetro la clase que se supone que debe instanciar, aunque puede instanciar otra cosa, como de hecho hace nuestra factoría.

### Más detalles

Cuando el código hace por ejemplo:

```
n = Numero("10")
```

ocurre lo siguiente:

1. Python invoca `Numero.__new__(Numero, "10")` y recoge el valor que ésta devuelva en una variable temporal, llamémosla `obj` (si `Numero` no implementa `__new__()`, se llamará al `__new__()` de su clase base, pero pasándole `Numero` como primer parámetro)
2. Python ejecuta `obj.__init__("10")` y retorna `obj`
3. Se asigna ese `obj` a la variable `n`

En tu caso, el paso 1 va a causar una llamada a `super().__new__(NumeroEntero)`, es decir, una llamada a `object.__new__(NumeroEntero)`. Esta función está implementada internamente por python y hace la reserva de memoria necesaria para un objeto de tipo `NumeroEntero` (aún sin inicializar), y retorna esa referencia, que es retornada a su vez por tu función como resultado del `Numero.__new__()`

## Un efecto secundario imprevisto

De acuerdo con lo explicado, tenemos ahora un nuevo problema. ¡No podemos forzar que la instancia sea `NumeroDecimal` o `NumeroEntero` a voluntad. Por ejemplo:

```
>>> NumeroDecimal("10")
<__main__.NumeroEntero at 0x7fc22ff43950>
```

Aunque hemos pedido instanciar un `NumeroDecimal`, el resultado ha sido un `NumeroEntero`. Es previsible que esto ocurra porque el `NumeroDecimal.__new__()`, no está implementado, por lo que se va al de su clase base, se invoca `Numero.__new__()` y por tanto es la factoría la que decide el tipo, en base a la cadena "10".

Para evitar este problema deberíamos hacer que la factoría decida el tipo en base a la cadena, sólo si se está usando con la sintaxis `Numero("10")`, pero no si se llega a ella desde la sintaxis `NumerDecimal("10")`. ¿Cómo diferenciar estos casos? Pues por el primer parámetro `cls` que recibe la factoría, que sería `Numero` en el primer caso pero `NumeroDecimal` en el segundo.

Si `cls` *NO ES* `Numero`, entonces la factoría debe retornar un objeto del tipo especificado en `cls` y si es `Numero`, la factoría decidirá de forma inteligente según el valor de la cadena recibida.

Así pues:

```
class Numero:
    def __new__(cls, valor: str):
      if cls != Numero:
        return super().__new__(cls)
      if '.' in valor:
          return super().__new__(NumeroDecimal)
      else:
          return super().__new__(NumeroEntero)
```

Y ahora sí podemos ver que todo funciona como debe:

```
>>> Numero("10")
<__main__.NumeroEntero at 0x7fc22fdb4dd0>

>>> Numero("10.0")
<__main__.NumeroDecimal at 0x7fc22fdaa190>

>>> NumeroDecimal("10")
<__main__.NumeroDecimal at 0x7fc22fd529d0>  # Ok!

>>> NumeroEntero("10.0")
...
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10.0'
# Bueno, yo me lo he buscado...
```

Comment: Funciona a la perfección. Gracias, maestro.